# Change color of error highlighting (hard to read) in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I changed jupyter notebook's theme through jupyterthemes, but some of the error output is difficult to read, as it is white text with yellow highlights. How would I go about changing this?

I still want a dark themed background, which makes the text white, which makes it hard to read. I want to just change the highlighting color / error output, not the theme.

[Sample image of error output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKRrx.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand there is no native way to do this with jupyter / jupyterthemes.

A good alternative for me was using a browser specific extension such as [darker jupyter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/darker-jupyter/) for Firefox.

Hope this helps people in the same situation !